# how to validate wehther the URL given is from a specific domain or not in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```html
class Profile(models.Model):
    social_github = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to validate the URL to their respective domain
for example, the user should only be able to submit the URL of the `GitHub` domain in the Github field and if the user submits the URL with other domains he should get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a validator with the [**`urlparse(…)`** function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from urllib.parse import urlparse

def validate_hostname(*hostnames):
    hostnames = set(hostnames)
    def validator(value):
        try:
            result = urlparse(value)
            if result.hostname not in hostnames:
                raise ValidationError(f'The hostname {result.hostname} is not allowed.')
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError('invalid url')
    return validator
```

Then we can use this as validator:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    social_github = models.URLField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[validate_hostname('github.com', 'www.github.com')]
    )
    social_twitter = models.URLField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[validate_hostname('twitter.com', 'www.twitter.com')]
    )
    # ⋮
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class, you can write your own cleaning-functions for each field, by the name `def clean_<field>` e.g `clean_social_github`docs [here][1]

It takes as input only `self` where you can extract the data from each field e.g `data_github = self.cleaned_data["social_github"]`.

Then you would need to validate that the domain is what you expect - which can be done in different ways, e.g by just looking at what is between `www` and the first "." (which of course is a very naive approach) or check if "github" is in the url (or a better approach). Doing the latter would result in the following:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
class Profile(models.Model):
    social_github = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    
   def clean_social_github(self):
       data = self.cleaned_data["social_github"]
       if "github" not in data: #"github" is not in the url
            raise ValidationError(("Wups! Input only URLs from github),code ="invalid")
       return data #No problem in the url (What you return here, overwrites what is in self.cleaned_data["social_github"], so we just return the url which was input)
              


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/
```